# How to remove a relationship cleanly in Docrine 2?

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, persistence, cascade

There are entities `Endpoint`, `EndpointServerConfig`, and `Server`:

[image]

```
/**
 * Server
 *
 * @ORM\Table(
 *     name="server",
 *     indexes={
 *         @ORM\Index(name="fk_server_server_type_idx", columns={"server_type_id"}),
 *         @ORM\Index(name="fk_server_cluster_idx", columns={"cluster_id"})
 *     }
 * )
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Server
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=32, nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     *
     * @Groups({"export"})
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @var EndpointServerConfig[]
     */
    protected $endpointServerConfigs;
}

/**
 * EndpointServerConfig
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="endpoint_server_config", indexes={
 *     @ORM\Index(name="fk_endpoint_server_config_server_idx", columns={"server_name"})}
 * )
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class EndpointServerConfig
{

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var Server
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Server")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="server_name", referencedColumnName="name")
     * })
     *
     * @Groups({"export"})
     */
    protected $server;

    /**
     * @var Endpoint
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Endpoint", mappedBy="endpointServerConfig")
     */
    protected $endpoint;
}

/**
 * Endpoint
 *
 * @ORM\Table(
 *     name="endpoint",
 *     indexes={
 *         ...
 *         @ORM\Index(name="fk_endpoint_endpoint_server_config_idx", columns={"endpoint_server_config_id"}),
 *         ...
 *     }
 * )
 * @ORM\Entity
 * ...
 */
class Endpoint
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    protected $id;
}
```

Now I want to update an entity (e.g. `Foo`), that contains an `Endpoint`. Among other changes I want to remove the reference to the `Server` from the `Endpoint`'s `EndpointServerConfig`. That means for the database: The `endpoint_server_config.server` needs to be set to `NULL`.

I load the `Foo` to a `Zend\Form`, disable the server and submit the changes. On the server side I unset the `EndpointServerConfig#server` over `Foo`:

```
/** @var Foo $myFoo */
if(! $myFoo->getEndpoint()->getEndpointServerConfig()->getServer() || ! $myFoo->getEndpoint()->getEndpointServerConfig()->getServer()->getName()) {
    $myFoo->getEndpoint()->getEndpointServerConfig()->setServer(null);
}
$this->entityManager->persist($myFoo);
$this->entityManager->flush($myFoo);
```

It leads to an error:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'UPDATE server SET name = ? WHERE name = ?' with params ["", "someservername"]:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mydb`.`endpoint_server_config`, CONSTRAINT `fk_endpoint_server_config_server` FOREIGN KEY (`server_name`) REFERENCES `server` (`name`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

That means, Doctrine tries to `UPDATE` the `Server`, instead of just to remove the reference to it from the `EndpointServerConfig`. But why?

Only when I manually set `endpoint_server_config.server_name` to `NULL` (directly in the database), I can save the changes via form and Doctrine.

**How to get it working?**

---

**EDIT**

Just noticed, that I get the same problem on every update of the `EndpointServerConfig`. So not only on `setServer(null)`, bu also when I try to set a new `Server`. In this case the attempts leads to the error:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'UPDATE server SET name = ? WHERE name = ?' with params ["newservername", "someservername"]:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mydb`.`endpoint_server_config`, CONSTRAINT `fk_endpoint_server_config_server` FOREIGN KEY (`server_name`) REFERENCES `server` (`name`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following:-

```
 cascade={"persist", "remove"}
```

on your relation.

```
 @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Server", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
```